# Does there exist a documentation of the Javascript Liferay Service library? How is it possible to handle error cases?

Tags: javascript, service, liferay, liferay-service-builder

Liferay provides portlet developers Javascript code, which allows to call Liferay Services. When browsing the available API methods at `/api/jsonws`, a Javascript snippet is provided, which shows how this method can be called:

```
Liferay.Service(
  '/method',
  {
    parameter: 'value'
  },
  function(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
  }
);
```

However, I can't find a real documentation of this feature. While this example perfectly shows how a Service method can be called, it doesn't show how one can handle error cases.

When trying to find a documentation online, I also just found examples which showed how to call an API function, but not how to handle special cases, just like the above provided code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors can be handled following way:

```
    .
    .
    .
    function(message) {
        var exception = message.exception;

        if (!exception) {
            // Process Success
        }
        else {
            // Process Exception
        }
    }
```

**Reference:** http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/json+service+api

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask where you got that information from? I would like to see exactly how the service method is specified, instead of implementing by trying and guessing the specifics...

Comment: I have added the reference.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't include much more information but thanks anyway